# Android Conversion to Dalvik parse error

Tags: android, ant, dalvik

I am getting this error when I complie an Android project:

```
[2014-12-22 14:43:46 - ScriptingLayerForAndroid] Dx 
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: class name (net/londatiga/android/CustomPopupWindow) does not match path (bin/classes/net/londatiga/android/CustomPopupWindow.class)
[2014-12-22 14:43:46 - ScriptingLayerForAndroid] Dx     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:520)
...
...while parsing bin/classes/net/londatiga/android/CustomPopupWindow.class

[2014-12-22 14:43:46 - ScriptingLayerForAndroid] Dx 14 errors; aborting
[2014-12-22 14:43:46 - ScriptingLayerForAndroid] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

What could be the problem, a few days earlier the application worked just fine.
UPDATE:

When I close an included project it seems that it can't find its own R, and it imports it from another project I just closed.

I also get R.java was modified manually! Reverting to generated version!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same problem, and it was caused by a class conflict with two jar files. Check if you have two jar files containing same class.

Comment: Do you know a method to verify where is the conflict?

Comment: No sorry, you should check your buildpath for duplicate jar files, or duplicate class files.